# RSA - Data cannot be longer than the modulus error

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, rsa

In my C# application I'm encrypting data with a public key. Then I'll send the encrypted data to a nodejs-server. On the server I'm trying to decrypt the data with the private key. On the server-side, I'm getting the crypto-error, that the data cannot be longer than the modulus.

The data, I'm encrypting is only 32 Bytes long, the keys are 4096 Bit generated RSA keys.

Thats the code, which encrypts the data with the public key:

```cs
using (var RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    var RSAParams = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
    RSAParams.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(PublicKey.Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", ""));
    RSA.ImportParameters(RSAParams);

    EncryptedMessage = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

And on the server side, I'm using the crypto module to decrypt the message with the private key:

```js
var pathToPrivateKey = path.resolve('./private.pem');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(pathToPrivateKey, "utf8");

var decryptedMessage = crypto.privateDecrypt({
    'key': privateKey,
    'passphrase': 'passphrase',
    'padding': crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
}, dataToDecrypt);
```

I noticed, the data byte-array before encrypting is 32 bytes long, after encrypting it is 294 bytes long.

So the encrypted message is 294 bytes long when it arrives on the server. Is this intended?

Comment: Are you using x64 VS setting?  RSA has both a old 32 bit mode and a new 64 bit mode.  I seen issues when going to 64 bit compiler option it is also changing the RSA mode.  I suspect you key is only 32 bits and going to 64 bit compiler option is the cause of issue.

Comment: @jdweng you mean, if I compiled the C# application in 64 Bit or 32 Bit?

Comment: The project has settings for different modes there is a x86 option and a x64 option.  Last week when I did research I found following WIKI : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms  Older RSA uses 256 bits and Newer uses 512.  In net 4.8 is looks like there is a new class called SH1.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha1cng?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'm using the x64 mode..

Comment: Try compiling without x64 and see if same error occurs.  I never got response from issue last week to see if OPs fixed issue.

Comment: Tried it before, but didn't change anything on the result I'm getting.

Comment: There are a lot of different combination of options.  Padding is one option which makes output a multiple of the mode like 9 x 32 = 288.  Check to make sure encrypted size matches what is received.  Error could be due to dropping bytes.  The encrypted message and decrypt input must be exactly the same.

Comment: Your public key import is bogus (you’re importing a PKCS#1 public key as a Modulus, but it is a complex structure that /contains/ the modulus. I can’t easily search dupes right now, but this is an asked and answered problem. The encryption output of RSA is always equal to the key size (in bytes), no matter what options are used with it. But since you and the other party disagree on the size of the modulus they think your data is too long.

Comment: I got it working! Now I'm using the BouncyCastle library to encrypt the data with the public key.